# Alternative to global variables/constants

Tags: c++

I keep reading that using global variables is bad programming design, but does that mean global constants are also bad?

What alternatives are there instead of global variables/constants and what's the best way to declare constants that's needed in multiple source files ?

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Comment: global variables are bad if they are used wrong. and most of the time they are misused / stuff can be implemented in a better way without. you could take a look at singletons http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_%28Entwurfsmuster%29  but they can be misused also

Comment: From what I have read, Singletons are just as bad as global variables?

Comment: @cppanda not sure if you know this, but singletons are considered bad as well :). Generally, everything that represents global state is. Just because you wrap the variables inside a class doesn't magically make it ok. There are cases where globals are needed, but, as you correctly pointed out, most of the time they are misused.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore yes, at the end of the comment i said "they can be misused also". i don't use singletons or globals in my everyday applications, but there are cases when they are usefull.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The primary reason behind global variables being bad is reliance of shared state, which makes it easy for different parts of a program to cause unanticipated interference with other parts of the program by manipulating the shared state in ways that you did not intend to, making the program more error prone, hard to debug, and hard to maintain.

Constants, on the other hand, are pretty much okay, except for the fact that they pollute the global namespace (which might cause unintended consequences at compile time by changing the meaning of a symbol in the compilation unit). If you can declare them in a specific namespace/scope, then you're going to be fine.

Answer (score 4):

The real problem with global variables is that they encourage change from many points in the code.  Functions that do something also have the [side effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29) of changing global state (in fact, [Functional Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) does not allow side effects at all to avoid this pitfall).

That programming style is hard to properly debug and maintain.

Keep data close to where it is used so that there is a well-defined mechanism to alter it.

Global constants do not suffer from the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables lead to practical problems from large (often unknown) amounts of code relying on shared state. This can (does) lead to interactions that are hard to understand, trace, etc. In short, lots of code ends up tightly coupled, which will often lead to problems.

Global constants are mostly a (potential) philosophical problem. Since they are constant, most of the real problems from global variables never arise. At the same time, it's perfectly reasonable to question whether a particular constant really *should* be global or not. If (for example) you were dealing with physics, defining the speed of light as a global constant might make sense. Depending on the field, things like Pi, e, etc., can make sense as globals as well. On the other hand, if you can reasonably restrict the *need* for such things to less code, that's generally preferable. The value of Pi isn't going to change, but something like

```
 x = area(some_circle);
```

tends to be more readable/understandable than:

```
x = some_circle.radius * some_circle.radius * Pi;
```

Comment: True, but it's just as reasonable to question whether a particular free function should be global. (In a way, free functions _are_ global constants anyway.) If you need a mini-function such as `area` in just one place in the whole program, but possibly also `diameter` etc., I'd say rather let _π_ be global and use it to define the functions right where they're needed, with a quick comment for each.